# Save error in database Golang

Tags: go

I'm running http request in golang

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
```

So, it returns error back to the main function, that attempts to store it in the database:

```
_, err = db.Exec("UPDATE test SET error = $1 WHERE id = $2", error, id)
```

I receive the following error: `sql: converting Exec argument #1's type: unsupported type errors.errorString, a struct exit status 1`

So, I understand, that error has a different type, but I can't find information on how to pass the value of the error to the string. Could someone direct me in a right way.

Comment: The `error` type has just one method. It might suit your needs. On any case: Take the Tour of Go. Twice.

Comment: `error.Error()` will give you the string value. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function:

```
error.Error()
```

to get a string representation of the error.

*Tip:* avoid naming variables with existing type names. `error` is a type name and it's also your variable name, which might lead to confusion.